# Load modules dynmically in perl

Tags: perl, import, module, dynamically-generated

I want to have a lot of functions stored in a folder and include them in a main script.

For example, I have this library ABC1.pm:

```
package ABC1;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $var1 = 'abc1';

sub func1 {
    print "$var1\n";
}

return 1;
```

Another one called ABC2.pm:

```
package ABC2;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $var2 = 'abc2';

sub func2 {
    print "$var2\n";
}

return 1;
```

Both files are saved under a folder libraries
Now I run the main script which looks into the folder for all the file that are inside and tries to load them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#script.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {push @INC, './libraries/.'}
# use ABC1;
# use ABC2;

my $dir = './libraries';
my @libraries;
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
    print "$file\n";
    $file =~ s/\.pm$//;
    print "$file\n";
    push @libraries, $file;
}

eval {
    foreach my $library (@libraries){
        require $library;
        $library->import();
    }
    1;
} or do {
   my $error = $@;
   print $error;
};

ABC1->func1();
ABC2->func2();
```

If I just run it with the use statment entered manually it works. But if I want to use the piece of code which is not commented I get the following error:

> Can't locate ABC1 in @INC (@INC contains:
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
>   C:/Strawberry/perl/lib . ./libraries/. ./libraries/.) at abc.pl line
>   25. Can't locate object method "func1" via package "ABC1" (perhaps you forgot to load "ABC1"?) at abc.pl line 34.

But the path libraries is displayed in the @INC, so I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Missing extension could be the issue, and so could a lack of permissions to read the file. I can't think of anything else right now.

Comment: Importing at run-time (`$library->import();`) rarely makes sense. Not the issue you're asking about.

Comment: `next if ($file =~ m/^\./);` should be `next if $file =~ /^\./ || $file !~ /\.pm\z/;` cause `require` only looks for `.pm` files.

Comment: You should be using `$RealBin` instead of `.` (obtained using `use FindBin qw( $RealBin );`) to locate files relative to your program. Not the issue you're asking about.

Comment: `BEGIN {push @INC, './libraries/.'}` can be written more cleanly as `use lib 'libraries';` (or `use lib "$FindBin/libraries";` as suggested above).

Comment: @ikegami actually that was the problem, so the sytaxis of requiere includes the extension but the one of "use" does not.

Comment: Oops, yeah, got it backwards. `require EXPR` requires a path

Comment: (In the original comment, I meant the file name might have been missing its extension.)

Comment: Your logic escapes me. If you want to load all modules with all functions then why not just add a bunch of `use [Module]` at top of the code? If you load all functions them may be it makes sense to put them all into one module instead. It would make more sense to store names of _desired modules_ in an array an load only them dynamically.

Comment: Perhaps you did not formulated you question correctly. I guess that you want to know where to store your generated modules in **Strawberry perl** tree. From your post I can see that proper location would be **C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `use MODULE` and `require MODULE` expect the name of a module, the `require EXPR` syntax of `require` expects a path to a file.

It can be a path relative to a path in `@INC`.

```
require "Foo/Bar.pm";
```

It can be a path relative to the current directory.

```
require "./Foo/Bar.pm";
```

It can be an absolute path.

```
require "/some/dir/Foo/Bar.pm";
```

---

Fixed and cleaned up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin qw( $RealBin );  # Get the location of this program.

my $plugins_dir_qfn = "$RealBin/libraries";

my @libraries;
opendir(my $dh, $plugins_dir_qfn) or die $!;
while (my $fn = readdir($dh)) {
    next if $fn =~ /^\./ || $fn !~ /\.pm\z/;

    my $qfn = "$plugins_dir_qfn/$fn";
    #print "$qfn\n";

    eval { require $qfn; }
        or warn("Can't load \"$qfn\": $@");
}

ABC1->func1();
ABC2->func2();
```